# Vagrant Laravel Homestead SSH authentication failed

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, vagrant

On `vagrant provision` of Laravel Homestead I get `SSH authentication failed!` and the Vagrant instance won't run.

> SSH authentication failed! This is typically caused by the public/private
>   keypair for the SSH user not being properly set on the guest VM.

This seems to have started from the error when I first provisioned homestead:

```
==> default: tee: /home/vagrant/.ssh/authorized_keys: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 10):

Having the default folder mapped to `/home/vagrant` in the `Homestead.yaml` was causing the issue.

This was my folders setting:

```
folders:
    - map: /Users/username/www
      to: /home/vagrant
```

Adding a folder deep fixed the problem:

```
    folders:
        - map: /Users/username/www/homestead
          to: /home/vagrant/www
```

Working :)

Perhaps someone can elaborate as to why this happens?

Comment: I believe the problem is that if you mount to just /home/vagrant, you end up overwriting the home folder of the "vagrant" user, so it wouldn't have access to any of it's files, especially the dot (.) files.  So things like the .ssh directory, etc, would not be available or writable.  Like if that user's home folder was wiped clean.  And that user is the default user for the system, and the one the Homestead scripts tries to copy the keys to.  Moving one directory down makes the home folder available while mounting your shared folder.

Answer (score 0):

did you set your ssh key to the correct path?

```
authorize: <SSH KEY PATH TO YOUR PRIVATE KEY>

keys:
    - <SSH KEY PATH TO YOUR PRIVATE KEY>
```

if you didnt set them right it cant connect

**EDIT**
You should not match your project to the root folder, because it matches the Homestead repository to your `/home/vagrant/` path

Comment: Yes the ssh keys were set correctly. The issue was strangely enough due to the folder mapping directly to `/home/vagrant`. Adding one folder deep fixed the issue. Cheers

Comment: surely not twice the private key